# failed to resolve: maybe a missing crate `image`? Rust

Tags: image, rust, rust-cargo

I'm attempting to start my first project in Rust using VScode. I added the '''image = "0.24.5"''' to the dependencies section of the Cargo.toml file, built the project with `cargo build`. However, whenever I try and run the file I get an error that says:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: maybe a missing crate `image`?
 --> main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use image::io::Reader;
  |     ^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `image`?
  |
= help: consider adding `extern crate image` to use the `image` crate
```

This is the main file:

```
use image::io::Reader;


fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "imaging"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
image = "0.24.5"
```

Not quite sure why I'm getting this error. My guess is that it may be that VScode is unable to find the dependency.

Comment: Works for me ... :/ How did you create said project? With `cargo new`? Did you `File` -> `Save All`? (maybe your `Cargo.toml` isn't saved yet)

Comment: *"built the project with `cargo build`"* - If that works, running should work as well. How are you running it? With `cargo run`? Or with `./target/debug/imaging`?

Comment: So I just checked and it DOES run from the cmdline. But for some reason when try and run it through VS Code "Run Code" button, I get the error. @Finomnis

Comment: When you copy the command it executes, does it work?

Comment: And more general, what **is** the command it executes?

Comment: Also, which 'run code' button do you mean? There is only 'Run' directly above `fn main()` (if you have the rust-analyzer plugin installed, which I highly recommend). Apart of that, there is 'Start without Debugging' and 'Start Debugging'. I am not sure what you mean with the 'run code' button.